# Missing built-in command "history" for Tcl C extension

Tags: c, tcl

I am working on a project need Tclsh like support with some self-defined commands. I implemented following code (based on Tcl 8.5):

```
Tcl_Main(argc, argv, Tcl_AppInit);
```

And put new commands registration in Tcl_AppInit. Everything looks fine, except that with the new command line interpreter, when I type Tcl built-in command "history", I got :

```
% history
invalid command name "history"
```

Other built-in commands work fine, like "puts", "set", etc. 
Why ? Do I have to implement my own "history" command instead?

Comment: Solved the mystery : 
It turns out "history" is part of Tcl script library which needs to be sourced during initialization, either by sourcing $TCL_LIBRARY/init.tcl or calling Tcl_Init(interp).

Comment: You may add this comment as a answer and accept it—that's a normal practice on SO: there's nothing wrong with the fact you solved this yourself ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Add my solution here:
It turns out `history` is part of Tcl script library which needs to be sourced during initialization, either by sourcing `$TCL_LIBRARY/init.tcl` or calling `Tcl_Init(interp)`.